# Setup Lint for Angular workspace

Tags: angular

I've tried to setup linter for my angular projects, however I cannot find instructions on how to execute it for workspaces.

I've also tried it with brand new project but still no luck.

```
Steps to replicate:
ng new my-workspace --no-create-application
cd my-workspace
ng g app app1 --routing true --style scss
ng g app app2 --routing true --style scss
ng lint

Cannot find "lint" target for the specified project.
You can add a package that implements these capabilities.

For example:
  ESLint: ng add @angular-eslint/schematics

Would you like to add ESLint now? Yes
```

This installs lint but it doesn't make any changes to angular.json file.
Based on documentation for [ng lint here](https://angular.io/cli/lint) it is meant to update angular.json with the linter for the projects.

Other things I have tried is to run the ng lint from inside app1 folder as well as manually configure lint but nothing has worked.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around i found this gem in the github issues around adding lint to workspaces.

In root of workspace run

```
ng add @angular-eslint/schematics
```

For each child project, run:

```
ng g @angular-eslint/schematics:add-eslint-to-project <your-project-name-goes-here>
```

Link to the Github Issue [here](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/issues/632#issuecomment-1035180154)

Comment: That made it working. Strange this isn't documented properly